# ESP-IDF fails cMake during example project (blink) when trying to include main

Tags: cmake, esp32, esp-idf

I'm trying to get the ESP-IDF to run on Ubuntu 18.04. When I try to compile the test project blink using "idf.py build", I get an error from cmake.

The original code that fails is in /home/bjorn/esp/esp-idf/tools/cmake/scripts/component_get_requirements.cmake

The command that fails is this:

`include(${__component_dir}/CMakeLists.txt OPTIONAL)`

It generates the error " include called with wrong number of arguments.  include() only takes one file."

Removing the OPTIONAL keyword changes the error to "include called with invalid argument: code/ESP-IDF"

I added a few more lines before the one that generates the error in order to try to understand what's going on:

```
message( "listing component values")
message(${__component_name})
message(${__component_dir})


include(${__component_dir}/CMakeLists.txt)
```

This generates a long list of component, until one fails. It is main:

```
listing component values

main

  
/xxx/ESP-IDFtutorial/blink/main


CMake Error at
/xxx/esp/esp-idf/tools/cmake/scripts/component_get_requirements.cmake:102
  (include):

include called with invalid argument: code/ESP-IDF

Call Stack (most recent call first):

/xxx/esp/esp-idf/tools/cmake/scripts/component_get_requirements.cmake:120 (__component_get_requirements)
```

I'm really not sure where to go from here. Is there some variable that I need to set to get this right? Or is there some incompatibility somewhere?

Answer (score 2):

Ugh, I found the issue: some directories in the path to main had spaces in their name.

When I relocated my code directory, everything started working smoothly.